# Date object from json response

Tags: javascript, json, date

Hi I have a scenario where I need to convert the JSON response to a date object so that I can display it in different format.
Here is the JSON response what I am getting:

```
responseData: [{"id":10,"createdDate":"1 Sep, 2014 12:48:52 PM"}]
```

In the UI i need display create date as **1 Sep, 2014** or I need to display it in **mm-dd-yyyy** formate.
How can I do this? Do I need to create date object from json response or I should play around with parsing the json reponse?
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

just add [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to your page

```
moment(responseData[0].createdDate).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code hope works

```
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year
alert(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Manipulate date object after creating json obj as follows -->
`new Date(JSON.parse('[{"id":10,"createdDate":"1 Sep, 2014 12:48:52 PM"}]')[0].createdDate)`

Answer (score 0):

pass  `data.createdDate` to `renderdate` function

```
function renderDate(value) {        
    var getDate;
    if (Date.parse(value)) {
        getDate = new Date(value);
    }

    //used for json date format like /Date(1224043200000)/
    else {
        getDate = new Date(parseInt(value.substr(6)));
    }

    return ((getDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + getDate.getDate() + "-" + getDate.getFullYear());
}
```